# kube-dns pods does not run when install with kops

Tags: kubernetes, kops, kube-dns

I've setup a standalone k8s cluster using kops, so I want all pods running on only 1 master too. The cluster started well but kube-dns and kube-autoscaler pods does not running, it's in pending status. This is node describe

```
kubectl describe nodes
Name:               ip-10-0-3-184.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
Roles:              master
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m3.large
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-southeast-1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-southeast-1a
                    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup=master-ap-southeast-1a
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-0-3-184.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
                    kubernetes.io/role=master
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
```

but `/var/log/kube-scheduler.log` is:

```
I0526 12:49:54.629475       1 scheduler.go:191] Failed to schedule pod: kube-system/kube-dns-autoscaler-787d59df8f-8jgn7
I0526 12:49:54.629570       1 factory.go:1251] Updating pod condition for kube-system/kube-dns-autoscaler-787d59df8f-8jgn7 to (PodScheduled==False)
I0526 12:50:09.706382       1 scheduler.go:191] Failed to schedule pod: kube-system/kube-dns-7785f4d7dc-rqzdq
I0526 12:50:09.706484       1 factory.go:1251] Updating pod condition for kube-system/kube-dns-7785f4d7dc-rqzdq to (PodScheduled==False)
I0526 12:50:10.632285       1 scheduler.go:191] Failed to schedule pod: kube-system/kube-dns-autoscaler-787d59df8f-8jgn7
I0526 12:50:10.632371       1 factory.go:1251] Updating pod condition for kube-system/kube-dns-autoscaler-787d59df8f-8jgn7 to (PodScheduled==False)
I0526 12:50:41.709687       1 scheduler.go:191] Failed to schedule pod: kube-system/kube-dns-7785f4d7dc-rqzdq
I0526 12:50:41.709796       1 factory.go:1251] Updating pod condition for kube-system/kube-dns-7785f4d7dc-rqzdq to (PodScheduled==False)
I0526 12:50:42.635260       1 scheduler.go:191] Failed to schedule pod: kube-system/kube-dns-autoscaler-787d59df8f-8jgn7
I0526 12:50:42.635361       1 factory.go:1251] Updating pod condition for kube-system/kube-dns-autoscaler-787d59df8f-8jgn7 to (PodScheduled==False)
```

I can fix it manually by using command
`kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`
but I want it is enable when I create the cluster with `kops create cluster`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Taints are set in kops templates for all types of [Kubernetes networking add-ons](https://github.com/prachetasp/kops/tree/master/upup/models/cloudup/resources/addons).

It is not possible for now to enable/disable that part of the template with command line options.

But, there is a possibility to configure the taints for an instance group:

```
kops edit ig master-us-west-1c
```

> [Instance Groups](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/instance_groups.md#instance-groups)
>   By default, a cluster has:
>
> - An instance group called nodes spanning all the zones; these instances are your workers.
> - One instance group for each master zone, called master- (e.g. master-us-east-1c). These normally have minimum size and maximum size
>     = 1, so they will run a single instance. We do this so that the cloud will always relaunch masters, even if everything is terminated at
>     once. We have an instance group per zone because we need to force the
>     cloud to run an instance in every zone, so we can mount the master
>     volumes - we cannot do that across zones.
>
> [Adding Taints or Labels to an Instance Group](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/instance_groups.md#adding-taints-or-labels-to-an-instance-group)
>   If you're running
>   Kubernetes 1.6.0 or later, you can also control taints in the
>   InstanceGroup. The taints property takes a list of strings. The
>   following example would add two taints to an IG, using the same edit
>   -> update -> rolling-update process as above.
>
> Additionally, nodeLabels can be added to an IG in order to take
>   advantage of Pod Affinity. Every node in the IG will be assigned the
>   desired labels. For more information see the labels documentation.

```
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2016-07-10T15:47:14Z"
  name: nodes
spec:
  machineType: m3.medium
  maxSize: 3
  minSize: 3
  role: Node
  taints:
  - dedicated=gpu:NoSchedule
  - team=search:PreferNoSchedule
  nodeLabels:
    spot: "false"
```

Comment: This is not my case, I have an instance group with only 1 master and 0 node, so I want to run pods on the master. This lead the above problem. But never mind, I solved this by create a custom user-data script to untaint the master to allow it allocatable pods